# boost C++ library crashed on perl_matcher match_all_states

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost library to link with my binary. I am getting the following crash trace in some situation. Could someone please point me what circumstance this could happen?

```
>>> Stack: #0 0x00007f1c6670f576 in boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const*, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >
>::match_all_states() () from /lib/x86_64/libboost_regex.so.1.55.0
#1 0x00007f1c6670f79d in boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const*, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >
>::match_prefix() () from /lib/x86_64/libboost_regex.so.1.55.0
#2 0x00007f1c6670fe72 in boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const*, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >
>::find_restart_any() () from /lib/x86_64/libboost_regex.so.1.55.0
#3 0x00007f1c66706ae5 in boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const*, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >
>::find_imp() () from /lib/x86_64/libboost_regex.so.1.55.0 <<<<
```

Comment: Where's your code? There could be a DoS pattern in the regex being exploited by a particular input. And then there's a zillion ways in which UB could arise (with corruption or ABI differences e.g.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you please give me one example string which can cause a crash of this API ..

Comment: No I cannot, because the bug is not there. See http://sscce.org and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve